# PHP Post , one php file for each function that posts data to my server

Tags: php, web-applications, post

Each time I post some info from my web app to the server i send it to a PHP file. this php file then calls a function that put the info into the database. This is the general idea right ? :)

The only problem is that I find myself creating a php file for each function call! I have one for creating a "task", one for creating a "user" one for toggleing a variable, one for setting a variable .....etc.

I don't know how else to do it. Even though I keep all my PHP database functions in one file, I find that I have to make a new file for each post call I do.

**Example 1**:

```
<?php
include 'databasefunctions.php';
inserttaskDB();
?>-
```

**Example 2**:

```
<?php
include 'databasefunctions.php';
inserthelpoffers($_POST[task_id],$_SESSION[id],$_POST[help_offer]);
?>
```

---

I find that I'm organizing my code badly. How can I better organize my code?

Comment: Hard to answer with that little exmplanation given... Maybe think that way: currently you create another API with each php script you implement. Instead you want only one single API you can reach via a single URL. So what do you have to change? You must enhance the single API to differ between different objects it is meant to handle. For example by specifying the type of object by an additional argument. Then the AIP (the php script) can react different depending on what type of object it is meant to process.

Comment: There is not a *correct* way to organize php files. *this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*

Comment: well i guess im looking for a best practice !? mabey there is not one right way, but is my way bad ???  Lets say that i added a parameter in the post call to differentiate between which functins i am calling, would that not be kind of messy? im just looking for a clean way to do this.

Comment: Ok mabey someone can point me to a good recourse explaing how to do this? that is a clear question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are doing. When you send a post request to a php page via your app ypu call a function in that file to store the data into db. The problem seems to be you send this post request to multiple PHP files instead of one. So here is a quick fix for this.

```
//I believe your databasefunctions.php has all the functions like
function inserttaskDB($task){
   //SQL query to insert
}

function inserthelpoffers($taskId,$id,$helper){
   // SQL query to insert helper offer
}
```

Now what you can do is have only one file like getDataFromMobile.php
so when you send data to getDataFromMobile send one more variable called func(for function)

```
//Now in your getDataFromMobile you can use a switch statement

$functionName = $_POST["func"];

switch($functionName){
    case "inserttaskDB":
        //Gets all your post iformation here and call the respective function
    break;
    case "inserthelpoffers":
      inserthelpoffers($_POST[task_id],$_SESSION[id],$_POST[help_offer]);
    break;
}
```

This is a very quick fix. I personally would tend towards OOP in such cases.

Hope this helps,
Dins

Comment: It definitly help it tells me that other people think its a valid option to take in an extra para meter to chose function. When you write Object oriented programming. what do you take by that ? could you please elaporate ?

Comment: when you write an application using MVC- design patterns ( kind of OOP) . you have 1 file where the class is defined and every function in that class is basically a page so. if you have a class GetMobileData it can have functions like public function insertTask() which can be used to insert the task .. and so on..  what about the answer I gave isn't that what you want?